# shinyDashboard with plotly & ggplot2 - Warning: Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, shinydashboard, ggplotly

Can one of you kind folk please help me out here - I've been tearing my hair out for a few days now!!

The below code is meant to produce an interactive plotly line chart, using ggplot formatting (no other reason than because it's relatively familiar to me), inside a shiny dashboard.

the first line chart (Australia) does not render automatically as app starts even though the start (min) and end (max) date values from the 'lf' dataset are there for it to read as defaults before any user inputs are entered. In the console and where the plot is meant to appear I receive the following warning:

**Warning: Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector**

Inside the app, the plot will only appear once I select a different date for the end value; changing the start date by selecting value from calendar will only cause the damn thing to spit the above warning at me again.

**Questions**

1. why is it not picking up the initial start and end dates from the dataset?
2. Is it waiting for user input to kick things off by design, if so,
   is there a way to have it run auto on startup using the initial date range?
3. Why does it not recognise the start date input but have no
   problems with the end date input?
4. what does the warning actually mean?
5. Am I plotting this correctly? should I cut out the ggplot/plotly combo?

Thanks guys!!

```
## app.R ##
library(base)
library(dplyr)
library(raustats)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)


#retrieve labour force dataset from ABS via abs.stat API
labour_force <- abs_stats(dataset = "LF", filter = list(ITEM=14, TSEST=c(20, 30)))
lf <- select(labour_force, -c(data_item, frequency, obs_status, unknown, agency_id,agency_name, dataset_name))

#change datatype of 'time' to date format 
lf$time <- paste("01", lf$time, sep = "-")
lf$time <- strptime(lf$time, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
lf$time <- as.Date(lf$time, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
str(lf)
```

```
#UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "this is a title"),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem(
        dateRangeInput(
          inputId = "dateRange",
          label = "Select the date range (monthly):",
          start = min(lf$time),
          end = max(lf$time),
          min = min(lf$time),
          max = max(lf$time),
          format = "M-yyyy",
          startview = "year",
          separator = "to",
          autoclose = TRUE,
          )
      ),
      menuItem("menu item", tabName = "menuItem1", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("ABS website", icon = icon("th"), href = "https://abs.gov.au"),
      menuSubItem("submenu")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(    
                box(
                  title = 'Australia',
                  status = "warning",
                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                  plotlyOutput("LFaus", height = 250),
                  width = 12
                )
              ),

              fluidRow(
                box(
                  title = 'Victoria',
                  status = "warning",
                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                  plotlyOutput("LFvic", height = 250),
                  width = 12
                )          
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "menuItem1",
              h2("welcome to menu item 1")
      )
    )
    )
)
```

```
#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  date_range <- reactive({
    filter(lf, between(time, input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2]))
  })


  output$LFaus <- renderPlotly({
   LFplt_aus <- ggplot(date_range() %>% filter(adjustment_type == "Seasonally Adjusted", age == "15 and over",  region == "Australia"), aes(x= time, y= values, colour= sex)) +
      geom_line()
    ggplotly(LFplt_aus)
  })

  output$LFvic <- renderPlotly({
    LFplt_vic <- ggplot(data = filter(lf, adjustment_type == "Seasonally Adjusted", age == "15 and over",  region == "Victoria")) +
      geom_line(aes(time, values, colour = sex))
    ggplotly(LFplt_vic)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I guess solved here later: https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinydashboard-with-plotly-ggplot2-warning-error-in-order-argument-1-is-not-a-vector/65742